# Entity Framework Code First: Many-to-Many relationship; Remove some Roles from the User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have a Many-to-Many User/Role relationship.

It’s OK, when I insert a new user into the database and add it in some roles.

But, how to remove some roles from the user? I don't want to completely remove user or role, I only want to:
1. Remove some Roles from the User;
2. Assign new Roles to the User.

My Classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking for, but I think it is that you want to be able to remove a role from a user, and that user from the appropriate role?

If so, you will know the user and role, and for this simple case want to make use of the [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) function.

```
void RemUserRole(User u, Role r)
{
    u.Roles.Remove(r);
    r.Users.Remove(u);
}
```

This will remove the items from the relevant list of each Role and User.

Edit:

To add new roles to users, you use the [List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method.

```
void AddUserRole(User u, Role r)
{
    u.Roles.Add(r);
    r.Users.Add(u);
}
```

This simply adds each item to the other's list of roles/users.